# Codeigniter tank auth check user entered password

Tags: codeigniter, tankauth

I'm using Tank Auth for my website.

I've searched for a function that would check if user has entered a valid password, when he tries to update his profile.

I don't understand how to hash password from user input that would match one in database.

Here's my controllers code:

```
            $password = $this->input->post('password');
            $hasher = new PasswordHash(
                $this->config->item('phpass_hash_strength', 'tank_auth'),
                $this->config->item('phpass_hash_portable', 'tank_auth')
            );
            $hashed_password = $hasher->HashPassword($password);
```

`$hashed_password` gives me different hash each time

I dont think that i should enable `phpass_hash_portable`

Any advices?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the CheckPassword module of the Tank Auth instead of hashing it by using the PasswordHash of the phpass.

Answer (score 0):

You can check your password by using this function:

```
$hasher->CheckPassword(password which has to be checked,password from database).
```

instead of encrypting yourself.

Note: password which has to be checked => is raw data
password from database => password from database.